# Can you use relative prediction intervals to compare models trained on a different response

Tags: prediction-interval

Is there a reason *not* to use a relative prediction interval ( PI/target_value, for a constant PICP) to compare models with different target variables?

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine since the information given by the interval is not changed by this transformation.